# Maya - Delete vs dissolve

Tags: maya, modeling

Perhaps a noob question, but I come from a Blender background and I'm having trouble in handling the different ways of deleting in Maya. Blender has a thing where it **always** asks you 'what' you want to delete among your selection. Like, even if you've selected edges, it asks if you want to delete those edges or the vertices among those selected edges, which is great since it avoids potential mistakes, imo.

I have a (capless) cylinder in Maya with 32 edge loops and I want to delete the edges that make up the 'rings' as well as faces they're attached to. This also means I **should** end up with an object that is a bunch of faceless edges along the axis of the cylinder, with 32 subdivisions (where the rings used to be). This works exactly as intended in Blender, but when doing it in Maya, the rings are 'dissolved' rather than 'deleted'.

If I try to delete these faces now, instead of 'delete faces only' (which is done the same way in Blender), it deletes the vertices along with them.

Result achieved in Maya (wrong):
[image]

Result achieved in Blender (correct):
[image]

Comment: Maya uses a bit different style polygon primitive than blender. So stuff arent triangles but genaralized holed ngons which have more kinds of forms than blenders primitive. So maya basically only ever deletes faces and freestanding points. A freestanding point is a point with 2 edges comming into it. Youll get used to this really quickly just keep doing it. Edges essentially always disolve, unless its a complete hole. You control what to delete by selection type. Anyway this isnt on topic here.

Comment: Id like to clarify a bit. The system is entirely self consistent if you think about what the generalized primitive is like. Its just not consistent in your mind because you think the way blender does primitives is made is the only way. I mean if deleting an egde between two polygons didnt create a new polygon how would you make 8 sided polygons out of things?

Comment: Anyway im happy to explain this in this sites chat (ink spot) if you are interested just not as an answer since its offtopic

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation, joojaa! Ngl, I was ready to face a different paradigm(?) when it came to modelling in maya vs blender, but I just didn't expect it to happen when it came to smth as simple as deleting lol.

Comment: But is there absolutely no way of deleting those rings including the faces attached? I did think it could be done in face mode, but if I delete two adjacent faces, the edge between them also gets deleted. Basically, any one of the techniques among "delete faces only" and "**delete** edge" would be a solution to the problem I'm facing.

Comment: I'm having trouble googling for answers as well since any search query involving 'delete edge maya' always gives me the dissolve result. I'm not aware of any special term in maya (if there are any) that explicitly deletes edges (such as 'cull edges' or smth idk).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135770/discussion-between-joojaa-and-spectraxcd).